# Pretty print JSON wrapped within XML element

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, pretty-print

I am trying to convert the following XML file into JSON format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
   <data>{"errorCode":"logon.invalid"}</data>
</soapenv:Body>
```

If the XML document is all XML elements  only, conversion works fine using Jackson and converts all the XML elements and prettyprints them nicely on the HTML page.  However when using example above I receive the following output:

```
[ {
  "data" : "{\"errorCode\":\"logon.invalid\"}"
} ]
```

I somehow need to be able to pretty print the JSON string that sits within an XML element.

Any ideas how I go about this using a library such as Jackson?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this by extracting the json part and processing that alone, instead of trying to parse the XML together with json string.

so this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
    <data>{"errorCode":"logon.invalid"}</data>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

becomes this:

```
{
    "errorCode" : "logon.invalid"
}
```